# Find the distribution of how a drunkard is walking

Tags: probability

I have another homework question, and part of it is throwing me for a loop. The question is (paraphrased):

A drunkard starts at position 0, and takes either one step forward (with probability p) or one step backward with probability (1-p). His steps are independent and p is constant. Let X denote his position after n steps.

Question: Find the distribution of (X+n)/2 and also find E(X).

I am confused by the first part of the question. If he's asking me to identify the type of distribution, I would say it's a binomial distribution, with E(X)=np. I feel like it can't be that simple, but I'm at a loss as to what he means by "find the distribution of (X+n)/2".

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Jon

Comment: this is exactly that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understood: do you mean that he is indeed just asking me to identify the type of distribution?

Comment: yes, he is. and your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had been asked to find the distribution of $X$ then it would have expectation $n(2p-1)$ support of just over half the integers in the interval $[-n,n]$, which is mildly complicated.

Instead looking at $Y=\dfrac{X+n}{2}$, the expectation becomes $np$ and the support is all the integers in the interval $[0,n]$.  You are correct when you identify it as a binomial distribution.

This is easy to see if you consider the drunkard's friend who wants to go home and refuses to go backwards, so steps forward when the drunkard does (i.e. with probability $p$) but stays still when the drunkard goes backwards (i.e. with probability $1-p$). $Y$ describes the friend's position after the drunkard has taken $n$ steps.